# javafx calling a class method from the controller class

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, eventhandler

I am working on a `Javafx` prject using the `Model View Controller` format. Currently in the model I have 3 classes: a school class, a major Class, and a student class. The school class has an array list of majors and the major class has an array list of students. The list of students are read in from `majorName.txt` files.

The View organizes and prints the lists of majors and students into text fields. One of the required methods is to be able to save any changes made to the text fields(As in someone using the application can change the name add a name delete a name etc.) after a save button is pressed. The Controller should not be saving and updating the files. It should instead call a method from the school class to do the saving.

**main.java**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            // Load the FXML document (we created with SceneBuilder)
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation( Main.class.getResource("../Main.fxml") );

            // Load the layout from the FXML and add it to the scene
            AnchorPane layout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();             
            Scene scene = new Scene( layout );

            // Set the scene to stage and show the stage to the user
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**School.Java**

```
public class School {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Major> majors;

    public School(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Major = new ArrayList<Major>();
    }

    public School loadData( ) {
    //reading .txt files to create instances of majors and students
    }

    public void Save( String houseName, String roster ) {
    //writing .txt files with changes from application textfields
    }
```

**maincontroller.java**

```
public class MainController implements EventHandler {
    @FXML private Text schoolName;
    @FXML private Text firstHouseName;    
    @FXML private Text firstHouseStudent; 
    //ect... LIST of all FXML nodes 

     public void initialize( URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //Create the school instance and call School.loadData() reading data to create major and students.
        School OCC = new School( "OCC");
        OCC.loadData();

    public void handle(Event arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String rosterOne = firstMajorStudent.getText();
        String nameOne = firstMajorName.getText();
        //OCC Cannot be resolved
        OCC.save(nameOne, rosterOne);
```

My issue is with the final line of code, calling the method Save from the class school. Do I need to pass the `OCC` object to the handle method?.

Comment: You will either need to pass it, or increase the scope of the `OCC` object.

Comment: Yes, but your `OCC` object is only useful for the `initialize` method. You need to increase the scope of that object to be useful inside all methods. You are declaring it as a `local variable` and you need it to be a `class/member variable`. This means that all methods can access that object.

Comment: Yes, thats not what I was saying. Please read up on [variable scope](https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) to understand what I was trying to say.